# Read "data.message" from Bundle

Tags: java, android

In the GCM server example, I can send the "data" with a payload:

```
collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.score=4x8&data.time=15:16.2342&registration_id=42
```

If I send without a payload, just `data=some_text`, on the client side, I can read it with

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
//...
s = extras.getString('data');
```

How do I read it if I have a payload? `s = extras.getString('data.score');` doesn't work.

**Edit:** Never mind. The answer was very clear on the GCM server imlementation website, I just didn't see it because of my nose:

> For instance, "data":{"score":"3x1"} would result in an intent extra
>   named score whose value is the string 3x1.

so, I have to read  `s = extras.getString('score');`, without the `data.`.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html#plain-text

Comment: @Selvin Heh, I read that page few times over, but ONLY after you posted the link the answer jumped in my face: "For instance, "data":{"score":"3x1"} would result in an intent extra named score whose value is the string 3x1." So I have to read extras.getString('score')!